# How can I monkey patch a gem that is managed in Bundler?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, monkeypatching

Specifically, I want to point delayed_job at a different table with:

set_table_name "my_table"

I just switched to Bundler from vendoring gems. I used to just change the code in the vendored gem, which was probably stupid. I probably need to do a monkey path for this anyway, I'm just no sure how.

Comment: Agree with @Justice... monkey-patching doesn't mean modifying the original source (necessarily), it just means re-opening the class and running amok ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I would do, is fork the project on github, and then implement a config option for the table name, and then send a pull request back to the original author.  In the meantime, I would point bundler at my own git (or company owned) repo.

Comment: That's a good idea, I need to take the extra step and start doing things the right way.

Comment: Mantain a personal fork for a minor change could be acceptable for a personal project, but in my experience could bring some troubles in projects of organizations were people join and left a project. And send a pull request is acceptable, but in this case isn't an improvement, is a customization that could have not any value for other users of that gem.

Comment: If you have an organization account with github, you make sure it is owned by that account so it will stay available if you leave the company.  By forking, the company has the option of merging upstream changes easily while maintaining the altered code... and again, makes pull requests easy.  Life is better if the feature is accepted upstream - then you can just switch back to the main gem.

Answer (score 5):

The following is the general pattern you can use. It's not going to work as-is, because the point is only to demonstrate the pattern, and because I don't know `Delayed::Job`'s class structure.

```
# config/initializers/delayed_job_patch.rb

require "delayed_job"

class Delayed::Job

  set_table_name "my_table"

end
```